# java code to highlight the color of text in pdf

Tags: java, itext

I am using `com.lowagie.text` in my pdf. While generating it, I need to highlight a few text.This is the code i have.I need the code for Highlighting text in a chunk.

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
Chunk chunck = new Chunk(arraySpec[k],font);
Phrase phrase = new Phrase(8.0f+ 1);

phrase.add(chunck);

ColumnText columnText = new ColumnText(cb);
columnText.addText(phrase);     

//verify the bounding box size
if (attributeBoundingBoxTextWidth == 0){
    attributeBoundingBoxTextWidth  = (int) boardWidth;
}
float llx = xpos;
float lly = 0;
float urx = llx + width;  

float ury = refYPos - sizeOftext;
refYPos = ury;
float leading = 8.0f+ 1;
columnText.setSimpleColumn(llx, lly, urx, ury, leading, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
columnText.go();
```

Comment: Your post doesn't say what your problem actually is. What is it you need help with?

Comment: Above code does not have highlight code in it and I dont know where to put it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for the above post.

```
 columnText.getCanvas().setColorFill(Color.decode("#FFA500"));
 columnText.getCanvas().rectangle(llx, ury-(leading) ,columnText.getWidth(phrase) , sizeOftext);
 columnText.getCanvas().fill();      
 columnText.go();
```